# Spring Roo: fill a new entity instance with initial data?

Tags: spring, initialization, aspectj, spring-roo, domain-object

I want to fill a new entity with auto generated data. For instance, I want to fill an entity field with a unique token. I'm thinking that this could be done in the constructor on the domain object.

To my suprise I can't find a constructor for the domain/entity classes generated by Roo. Do I break any guidelines by introducing a constructor myself? Or should I instead push in the persistency stuff from MyClass_Roo_Entity.aj and do it there? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's kosher or not, but here's how I ended up doing it.

- Created a no-arg constructor, as suggested [here](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-783).
- Added the necessary initialization in the constructor.

Seems to work perfectly well.